# Not storing duplicate files with AWS Versioning

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, versioning

I am trying to upload a large number of files to an AWS s3 bucket. I will also need to enable file versioning to have a backup incase some files get accidentally overwritten.

However, with AWS s3 versioning currently enabled when I upload the exact same file that is already there aws stores both versions of the exact same file. This is an issue as I will be uploading the same file multiple times and in that case, I would like the versioning to not be used to prevent excess data charges because of storing multiple version of the same object. However, if a change is made to the file then I would like aws versioning to be in use.

Is there a way to configure aws s3 bucket versioning such that duplicate upload files are ignored but changed or new files have versioning activated? (If it helps, the script that I am using to do this uses python and awscli)

Comment: S3 doesn't do this for you (what if your file were 3TB, for example?) So build a solution that maintains checksums for each uploaded file and compare them before you upload.

Answer (score 3):

S3 doesn't natively support this. If you upload the same file over and over again, a new version is added.

Depending on your use case, if using the AWS CLI, you could add the `--size-only` flag when using the [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command.

According to the docs adding this option:

> Makes the size of each key the only criteria used to decide whether to sync from source to destination.

So it will *only* copy files to S3 if the **size** of the file has changed.

This may or may not work for your use case, since it only factors in the size, so be sure to take that into consideration

Comment: this is not a good solution - size may remain the same while contents change. better to hash the files and compare hashes.

Comment: This exact point was clarified in the answer. Please offer a better solution

Comment: You can use something called s3.listObjectVersions which gives plenty of attributes to check the authenticity and other features of the file metadata.